# Serverless deployment error - AppleIdentityProvider - Provided private key cannot be used

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-serverless, idp

I am trying to deploy a serverless backend code to AWS. The code handles device registrations of ios devices with apple as Idp.

Got the following error:

```
Serverless Error ---------------------------------------
 
 An error occurred: AppleIdentityProvider - Provided private key cannot be used for Sign in with Apple. (Service: AWSCognitoIdentityProviderService; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterException; Request ID: c92xxxx-xxxxx-xxx-xx-x4c; Proxy: null).
```

Notes: A private key from a previous developer, is already present as a Parameter in Systems manager>>parameter store.

Q1) Does **sls deploy** expect a private_key to be stored on my laptop from where I am deploying?
Q2) I am dealing with backend code only, and not working on an ios app code directly. Why a private key is needed here?

Appreciate early response from experienced friends in this domain.

Many Thanks.

Comment: I got a new private key that says 
```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
<base64-line1>
<base64-line2>
<base64-line3>
UU/+3WA2
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```
Even this did not solve the problem

Comment: This is resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that your key has not been found. Please check your configuration files.
I think you lost the right key in your config files or the reference to the key is wrong

Answer (score 2):

This is resolved.

the right key reference was missing in one of the yaml files.